# AutoGenerateBindingRedirects doesn't work with unit tests

Tags: c#, mstest

Why doesn't this work in unit test projects?

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

I still get "Could not load file or assembly" errors if I don't add explicit binding redirects.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this:

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
```

You need both of them for unit test projects.

Comment: For some project types you will want to set these after `ResolveAssemblyReference` since some other target will set them to blank. In particular I found this for ASP.NET projects.

Comment: You're a lifesaver, I never would have figured this out!

Comment: Thank you, another episode of the "Most counter-intuitive MS concepts" series. I'd be interested what the motivation was behind this.