# .NET 4.8 Binding Redirect Guidance

Tags: c#, csvhelper, assembly-binding-redirect

I have a .NET 4.8 Framework WinForms project with the following NuGet packages:

- CsvHelper v30.0.1
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection v7.0.0

I am encountering the following error when running unit tests:

> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

It appears that:

- **CsvHelper** depends on **Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces v1.0.0**
- **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection** depends on **Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces v7.0.0**

I have tried the following fixes so far which have not fixed my error:

1. Make sure "Auto-generate binding redirects" is enabled in project Properties
2. Binding redirect to most recent version in the App.config:

```xml
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

3. Binding redirect to the version it wants:

```xml
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

4. Explicitly installing Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces v1.0.0 from NuGet. When I do this I get the following error:

```
Assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection' with identity 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' uses 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces' with identity 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
```

I'm a bit lost on how to get this all wired up correctly. Has anyone run into this scenario before and was able to fix it?

## EDIT

I failed to mention I was getting this error in my separate unit test project that is referencing my main project. It ended up being the main factor in this issue since the error was not occurring when debugging/executing the main project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there was an obscure setting needed in both projects in order for the auto generated binding redirect from a WinForms application to be recognized in the associated unit test project.

```xml
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects><!-- this was enabled already in both my projects -->
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType><!--  added this manually to both project files -->
```

Original answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46571808/9882482

Answer (score 2):

> CsvHelper depends on Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces v1.0.0

No.  It depends on >= 1.0.0

[image]

So under the rules for [NuGet package dependency resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution), this is a "[Cousin Dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#cousin-dependencies)" and the project will restore Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces v7.0.0, and generate this redirect

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Because that version is compatible with both packages.

Comment: Okay, sure. But I still have an error message saying it could not load the assembly. Even if I manually add the binding redirect you listed it is still giving me the error.

Comment: Create a new project with just those two NuGet packages and test.

Comment: I confirmed this works in a separate project with just the two NuGet packages, however this only leaves me even more confused/frustrated as to why I am getting this error when VS should be handling my binding redirects for me. What else am I missing?

Comment: If I remove the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection from the project, then it works fine. As soon as I add it back, the problem persists.

Comment: I have no idea.  But since it works in a simple project, add stuff to it until it breaks, or you have moved all your code to the new project.

Comment: I was worried you might say that :) your help is appreciated!

Comment: Well I spoke too soon, it seems it has something to do with it being a WinForms application, I originally recreated a Console Application to take all the variables out. Any ideas why that would impact it?

Comment: No.  It works in a simple .NET Frameworks Windows Forms app for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255749/discussion-between-shandy-sawyer-and-david-browne-microsoft).